# I have a Tableau Prep error fix involving setting an environment variable, and I don't know what that entails

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtual-environment, tabpy, tableau-prep

I am using a python script in Tableau prep, and this error keeps popping up:

System error: Failure loading FedOp: D:\tc\work\maestro-2021-2\g_pc\modules\platform\tabcore\main\parser\DataValueParser.cpp|`anonymous-namespace'::TupleParser::Parse|181 value - empty text

I found this article that I believe has the fixes for it. (https://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/tableau-prep-system-error-failure-loading-fedop)
I don't want to update Tableau Prep, but it does have one fix that does not involve that. It says to:

Set environment variable useJaxbSerialization=true

How do I do this? In the environment variable screen, do I just write, "useJaxbSerialization=true" for the Variable value and "Tableau Prep bug fix" for the Variable name? Also, I am using a virtual environment to run Tabpy, and if that is responsible for the error, I am not sure how to set an environment variable in a virtual environment. I am using Tableau Prep 2021.2.3.

Comment: If using windows, you can set the value in windows key -> edit env vars for your account -> then add the key and value. Restart Tableau prep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume they mean set the value in the System variables.

try:

1. On the Windows taskbar, right-click the Windows icon and select System.
2. In the Settings window, under Related Settings, click Advanced system settings.
3. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
4. Click New below 'System variables' to create a new environment variable
5. Input name `useJaxbSerialization` and value `true`